# Data binding in Knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have few controls in my MVC application bind with knockout.js example

```
<div class="checkbox">
<input class="styled" type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), checked: userProfileViewModel.preferredService, click: userProfileViewModel.toggleAssociation,attr:{id:Name(),name:Name()}">
<label data-bind="text: Name(),attr: { for:  Name()}"></label>
</div>
```

Here binding is done in below way

```
data-bind="value: id()
```

My App support multiple languages which i convert within razor syntax

```
<h3 class="title">@OtherLang("Some text to convert", language)</h3>
```

This method OtherLang("text", language) can be used directly on text as shown above or inside html attribute as below

```
<input type="text" value="@OtherLang(id(), language)" />
```

but in knockout way data-bind="value: id() , this c# method can not be used here.

Can someone suggest an alternative approach to adjust Otherlang() within knockout.js implementation to get it work here ?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you just mix-up some syntax here since you're going with razor c# through javascript?

The idea is that you have a string when the server has parsed your razor. So when you arrive on the client's browser you are assigning a string to the value object set through the data-bind 'value' property.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: '@OtherLang(id(), language)'" />
```